# ArrayList not storing objects

Tags: java, arraylist, project

Hello I am having trouble printing out items in my ArrayList. I can print it out in my PatronBorrow method but in PatronList and PatronReturn it does not print anything. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code? Thank you all very much

```
package proj1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Patron {

private int id;
private Book book;
private List<Book> books;

public Patron(int id){
    this.id = id;
    books = new ArrayList<Book>();
}

public int getID(){
    return id;
}

public List<Book> getBooks(){
    return books;
}

public void PatronBorrow(String b){
    book = new Book(b);
    books.add(book);
    System.out.println("Patron " + id + " has borrowed " + book.getTitle());
}

public void PatronReturn(String b){
    for(Book book : books){
        if(book.getTitle().equals(b)){
            books.remove(book);
            System.out.println("Patron " + id + " has borrowed " +     book.getTitle());
        }
    }
}

public void PatronList(){
    for(Book b : books){
        System.out.println("Patron " + id + " has borrowed " + books.size() + " item(s)");
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

}

```
package proj1;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project1 {

public static boolean isNumeric(String str){
    for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    String command;
    String line;
    Patron patron;
    int patronID;
    String title;
    String newTitle;
    String infile = args[0];

    if (args.length != 1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enter in file name");
    }

    try{
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(infile));
        while(file.hasNext()){
            command = file.next();
            if(isNumeric(command)){
                patronID = Integer.parseInt(command);
                patron = new Patron(patronID);
                command = file.next();
                if(command.equals("borrow")){
                    title = file.nextLine();
                    newTitle = title.substring(2, title.length() - 1);
                    patron.PatronBorrow(newTitle);
                }else if(command.equals("return")){
                    title = file.nextLine();
                    newTitle = title.substring(2, title.length() - 1);
                    patron.PatronReturn(newTitle);
                }else if(command.equals("list")){
                    patron.PatronList();
                }
            }else{

            }
        }

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found" + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: I don't see why it will not print anthing in  PatronList . Are you sure you are not re-initializing Patron object or may be calling the methods before you add a book object

Comment: Depending on how you are calling those methods, the last two methods in the class are bound to iterate over an empty list? Also, notice that you delete the only book you add in PatronReturn? What do you intend to achieve?

Comment: Can you add your main method to the question so we can see your code which is calling this class.

Comment: What happens when you try to print it out in the PatronReturn and PatronList methods? Are there actually books in the books arraylist to be printed?

Comment: Let's see the code that calls this.  There are a couple of minor issues here, but they shouldn't be keeping anything from getting printed -- in fact, they should be causing extra/wrong text to be printed, or causing exceptions to be thrown.

Comment: would you give me the `book` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the loop that uses the `Patron` class, you're creating a new (blank) `Patron` each time.

What you'll want to do, if you want to switch between patrons, is have a `Map<Integer, Patron> patrons` or the like in your main function.  Instead of creating a `new Patron(patronID)` each time, retrieve it from `patrons`, and only create one (and store it in the map) if there's not already one in there.

(As far as your `Patron` class, though, you might find if you do some real testing of that class that `PatronReturn` often throws an exception when you remove a book.  `ConcurrentModificationException`, namely, cause you're removing from a list you're iterating over at the time.  Just a heads up.)

Comment: oooooh i see now the second line in my file has another id so it creates a new one......Thank you! Also how does map differ from a list?

Comment: @user2127726: A map is a lookup table of sorts.  With a `Map<Integer, Patron>`, you store a `Patron` in such a way that you can look it up by the integer ID.

Comment: As for why you'd want a map rather than a list...that actually depends on the nature of your patron IDs.  If there will be gaps in the numbers, or they're several digits in length, a List would be a bad idea, cause you'll be wasting a bunch of space on list slots that may never have a value.  Maps are better if your lookup space is sparse like that.  If the IDs will always be like 1, 2, 3, etc, then a list would work as well, but that depends heavily on the data; the code alone doesn't allow me to make that assumption.